# How big websites handle with big traffic - common solutions

Tags: optimization, traffic

I wondered how big websites are handling thousands of visitors daily and how they handle with really big traffic.

I made research and discover that many of them are using Amazon Simple Storage Service, so they must have all pages ganerated as static html as it possible to storage only static files on the S3. Then also update of the website is not difficult (only replacing static files). Is it possible or I am wrong? Any other similar solutions?

Comment: @Shawn if all output came from the database, the pages would be far slower. The secret is that the output that comes from the database is minimized and cached as much as possible using tools like Memcache, APC, etc.

Comment: but I checked few big portals and they are usning S3 as a hosting, so that means that they are all cached into static pages. They are also more secure thanks to this.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo as a [fantastic article](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) about how to speed up websites and optimizing traffic.